# How to extract values from a column - Google Big quey

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking to extract $Revenue & $price value from a column which has values like below in a google big query, not sure how to use REGEX_EXTRACT or any other function to do so. Position of revenue & price varies in string so can have specific position.
Any thoughts how i do that?

```
Value 1 - 
{"utm_medium":"direct","utm_amplitude_user_id":"1580904318308","$quantity":1,"Locale":"English","$revenue":56.49,"Source":"App","utm_date":"2020-02-05","AppVersion":"Mac","$price":56.49,"utm_initial_medium":"direct"}

Value 2 -
{"utm_initial_source":"none",utm_medium":"direct","utm_amplitude_user_id":"1580904318308","$quantity":1,"Locale":"English","$revenue":56.49,"Source":"App","utm_date":"2020-02-05","AppVersion":"Mac","$price":56.49,"utm_source":"none","Device":"Desktop"}
```

Comment: Please share your implementation. It'll be helpful in understanding what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query.

> JSON_VALUE() function uses **double quotes to escape invalid JSONPath characters**.

see more information about JSON functions [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#standard_json_extraction_functions_recommended).

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT '{"utm_medium":"direct","utm_amplitude_user_id":"1580904318308","$quantity":1,"Locale":"English","$revenue":56.49,"Source":"App","utm_date":"2020-02-05","AppVersion":"Mac","$price":56.49,"utm_initial_medium":"direct"}' json UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"utm_initial_source":"none","utm_medium":"direct","utm_amplitude_user_id":"1580904318308","$quantity":1,"Locale":"English","$revenue":56.49,"Source":"App","utm_date":"2020-02-05","AppVersion":"Mac","$price":56.49,"utm_source":"none","Device":"Desktop"}'
)
SELECT JSON_VALUE(json, '$."$revenue"') AS revenue,
       JSON_VALUE(json, '$."$price"') AS price,
  FROM sample_data;

+---------+-------+
| revenue | price |
+---------+-------+
|   56.49 | 56.49 |
|   56.49 | 56.49 |
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Appreciate it. Cant upvote as it seems stackoverflow has limitation on new accounts to upvote it.

Comment: @mhkhan, no worries, that's enough if it helped..